# Wrong PUT method gets triggered in Akka Http using scala

Tags: scala, akka, swagger-ui, akka-http

In my APIendpoint class, I have 2 PUT methods lets say updateA and UpdateB but when I'm  trying to hit UpdateB using swagger it resolves to a UpdateA everytime. I dunno what I'm doing wrong because the code seems ok to me. Any help is appreciated.

```
 @Api(value = "/connectroutes", produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json",
    authorizations = Array(new Authorization(value = "")))
  @Produces(Array(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
  def routes: Route = {
    pathPrefix("sampleroute") {
      authenticateBasic(realm = "sample realm", authenticator) { authenticationResult =>
          updateA ~
          updateB
      }
    }


@PUT
    @Path("{name}")
    @Produces(Array(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    @Operation(summary = "sample", description = "UPDATE A",
      parameters = Array(new Parameter(name = "name", in = ParameterIn.PATH, description = "updateA name", required = true)),
      requestBody = new RequestBody(content = Array(new Content(schema = new Schema(implementation = classOf[A]), mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))),
    )
    def updateA: Route = {
      path(Segment) { name =>
        put {
          entity(as[A]) { a: A => {
            complete(updateAMethod(name, a))
          }
          }
        }
      }
    }

@PUT
  @Path("updateb")
  @Produces(Array(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
  @Authorization("basicAuth")
  @Operation(summary = "Sample", description = "Update B",
    requestBody = new RequestBody(content = Array(new Content(schema = new Schema(implementation = classOf[String]), mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))),
  )
  def updateB: Route = {
    path("updateb" / Segment) { namespace =>
      put {
        entity(as[String]) { updatedval: String => {
          complete(updatedVal))
        }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You API design is simply flawed. From a matching perspective a parametrized `/{id}` always matches `/updateB`. This is bad practice. You need to distinguish the end points more clearly such as `/a/{name}` instead of `/{{name}}` This doesn't have to do with Akka imo, I used various http frameworks in various different languages and I can't name a single one that would give the behavior you are expecting

Comment: Most frameworks allow you to have an ordered list, in which case `/updateB` could have more priority than `/{name}`. But as said above, it's bad design anyway.

Comment: in my case /updateB is the one that doesn't get called. it goes to {name} and there are a few more PUT methods in the class. Also i updated the code to something like /updateA/{name} and tried hitting /updateB, but it still goes to /update A. NOTE: there are around 4 PUT methods in the class and routing works perfectly for all of them. but calling the /updateB always hits only /updateA for some reason

Comment: fixed it! It was a problem with pathEnd being specified for certain routes that also had specific path associated to them. I removed the path for those routes and it works.